# Nested IF statement to create new column in R

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, cluster-analysis, analytics

I'm new at R, and trying to learn. Here is a much reduced df I'm working with. Pretend this is about 90 locations all using city abbreviations

```
df$Location <- c("SEA", "DEN", "CHI", "NYC")
```

I am trying to add a column called TimeZone by using this formula

```
if(df$Location==c('SEA')){
  df$TimeZone <- "PST"
} else {
  if(df$Facility==c('DEN')){
  df$TimeZone <- "MST"
} else {
  if(df$Location==c('CHI')){
  df$TimeZone <- "CST"
} else {
 if(df$Location==c('NYC')){
  df$Location <- "EST"
  }
  }
  }  
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengththe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengththe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengththe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: You need `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with a nested `ifelse` or `case_when` which are vectorized when compared to `if/else` (takes a scalar - length of 1)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(TimeZone = case_when(Location == 'SEA' ~ 'PST',
                                Location == 'DEN' ~ 'MST',
                                 Location == 'CHI' ~ 'CST',
                          Location == 'NYC' ~ 'EST'))
```

---

If there are many elements, create a key/value dataset and do a join

```
keyval <- data.frame(Location = c('SEA', 'DEN', 'CHI', 'NYC'),
                 TimeZone = c('PST', 'MST', 'CST', 'EST'))
left_join(df, keyval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some base R options:

---

- Use `Vectorize` + `switch`

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  switch(x,
    "SEA" = "PST",
    "DEN" = "MST",
    "CHI" = "CST",
    "NYC" = "EST"
  )
})
```

and then use `f` like below

```
df$timezone <- f(df$location)
```

---

- Use `match`

```
df$timezone <- c("PST", "MST", "CST", "EST")[match(df$location,c("SEA", "DEN", "CHI", "NYC"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are new with `R` it is good to know that you must create a dataframe with a code like this:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Location=c("SEA", "DEN", "CHI", "NYC"),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

As you have conditions you can use vectors to save results and then assign the values:

```
#Create conditions
c1 <- df$Location=='SEA'
c2 <- df$Location=='DEN'
c3 <- df$Location=='CHI'
c4 <- df$Location=='NYC'
```

After that you can assign the desired values first creating an empty variable:

```
#First create an empty var
df$TimeZone <- NA
#Replace
df$TimeZone[c1]<-'PST'
df$TimeZone[c2]<-'MST'
df$TimeZone[c3]<-'CST'
df$TimeZone[c4]<-'EST'
```

The output:

```
  Location TimeZone
1      SEA      PST
2      DEN      MST
3      CHI      CST
4      NYC      EST
```